# Populate UITableView section header title since section == 2?

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview

I have a response array from server named `firstData` and it's have 12 elements.. It's a bunch of dictionaries inside, and I do some filter to separate it to 3 different arrays like this:

```
    //filter to get all type Switch into one array.
    self.dataSwitchOnly = self.firstData.filter {
                    $0.type.rawValue == "Switch"
                }// 7 elements

//looping dataSwitchOnly to get all shop type.
                for i in 0..<self.dataSwitchOnly.count {
                    if (self.dataSwitchOnly[i].search_key == "shop_type" || self.dataSwitchOnly[i].search_key == "is_certified"){
                        self.shopTypeArr.append(self.dataSwitchOnly[i])
                    }
                }// 2 elements

//filter original data to get all elements are not have type Switch.
                self.dataAfterFilterSwitch = self.firstData.filter {
                    $0.type.rawValue != "Switch"
                }//5 elements
```

My UITableView `numberOfSections` like this:

```
//return filtered array which is not type `Switch` then + 2 more static section 0 and 1.
    return dataAfterFilterSwitch.count + 2
```

And because `shopTypeArr` and `dataSwitchOnly` does not have same name. So I have to hard code the header title of them in section 0 is Quick Filter and section 1 is Shop Type.

Now I wanna show my `dataAfterFilterSwitch` from section 2 to the end of tableView. But when I set `dataAfterFilterSwitch[section]` to get attribute `name`, I'm getting error `index out of range`. Maybe my question is so confused with you guys but I can provide more code for solve this problem.

Where's the wrong in my code logic?

my `viewForHeaderInSection`:

```
let itemFilter = self.dataAfterFilterSwitch[section-2]
//        header.isCollapse =  collapse[section]
//        header.delegate = self
        if section == 0 {
            let data = SectionHeaderModel(sectionTitle: "Quick Filter".uppercased())
            if header.isCollapse == 0 {
                header.sectionComponents?.bind(data: data, state: .collapse, imageState: ImageDataType.image(UIImage(named: "icon-24-chevron-bottom")!), target: self, selector:nil)
            }else {
                header.sectionComponents?.bind(data: data, state: .collapse, imageState: ImageDataType.image(UIImage(named: "icon-24-chevron-top")!), target: self, selector:nil)
            }
            return header
        }else if section == 1 {
            let data = SectionHeaderModel(sectionTitle: "Shop Type".uppercased())
            if header.isCollapse == 0 {
                header.sectionComponents?.bind(data: data, state: .collapse, imageState: ImageDataType.image(UIImage(named: "icon-24-chevron-bottom")!), target: self, selector:nil)
            }else {
                header.sectionComponents?.bind(data: data, state: .collapse, imageState: ImageDataType.image(UIImage(named: "icon-24-chevron-top")!), target: self, selector:nil)
            }
            return header
        }else {
            let data = SectionHeaderModel(sectionTitle:(itemFilter.name)!.uppercased())
            if header.isCollapse == 0 {
                header.sectionComponents?.bind(data: data, state: .collapse, imageState: SImageDataType.image(UIImage(named: "icon-24-chevron-bottom")!), target: self, selector:nil)
            }else {
                header.sectionComponents?.bind(data: data, state: .collapse, imageState: ImageDataType.image(UIImage(named: "icon-24-chevron-top")!), target: self, selector:nil)
            }
            return header
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you added two hard code sections in your tableView and you have to show your array's data after these sections. You must have to retrieve data from your array like this `dataAfterFilterSwitch[section - 2]`

Comment: I have to. But it's still crash by index out of range.

Comment: can you show me your code for cellForRow, numberOfSections and numberOfRows  delegates, otherwise it will be difficult to tell

Comment: I've update my question. Please reload. Or you can check my viewcontroller class in here: https://pastebin.com/q3CTstSn

Comment: add tableView.reloadData() after this 

 self.dataAfterFilterSwitch = self.dataBanDau.filter {
                $0.type.rawValue != "Switch"
            }
filterTableView.reloadData()